# Never read from a socket even though its being written to

Tags: python, sockets

I have a TCP socket that I'm writing to, the message protocol I'm working with is very simple and while there is a reply to every message I send I don't actually care about it and never need to examine it.

Can I simply *never* read from my socket even though I know it's being written to? Or is there a potential issue like running out of memory or having the socket refuse further writes or something of that nature?

Comment: One aspect of TCP is that each end is aware of how much buffer space the other end has.  Once the receive buffer at your end fills up, the other end will know it can't send any more data.  The exact result will depend on how the other end is programmed; I would expect an error to be generated, but it's conceivable that this error would be ignored, and your scheme of never reading data might actually work.

Comment: Ah, can I use something like /dev/null as my buffer?

Comment: Hmmm, on Unix-ish systems you might be able to use `os.sendfile()` to directly connect the socket to /dev/null (it's normally used in the opposite direction, though).  However, you'd need to do that in a separate thread, to keep from blocking your outgoing transfer, and if you're going to do that, you might as well just do a `.recv()`-and-ignore loop rather than deal with anything platform-specific.